# Small black circles with numbers around objective locations in Star Wars Battlefront

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

In Star Wars Battlefront 2015, I have noticed small black circles that have numbers in them next to locations of importance, such as control points.

Occasionally, they will have a yellow border, too. I am playing on an Xbox One, if it matters. Does anyone know what these mean?

Comment: I haven't played this in a couple months at this point, so I don't remember for sure. Could it be the indicator of the number of players in the zone?

Comment: @DCShannon That was my first guess, but I don't believe that is the case. I could be wrong though.

Comment: There definitely *is* an indicator of the number of players in the zone. If there's nothing else on the screen that might be that, then that's what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feature in which a player may point their gun in the general direction of the control point or objective indicator and press the use button, which on the Xbox One is X, to add a number to the existing total. Mainly used to show where you are concentrating your efforts, and this may be what you are seeing.